Mathematical properties used to derive Kraus operators
In this answer, it was very well explained why Kraus operators are not numbers as it might seem when reading Nielsen and Chuang for the first time. I have a minor, purely technical and probably simple question about the answer given.
The answer elaborates that:
$$
\begin{split}
\mathcal{E}(\rho_{\mathrm{in}}) &= \mathrm{tr}_{\mathrm{env}} \big[U(\rho_{in} \otimes |e_0\rangle_{\mathrm{env}}\langle e_0|_{\mathrm{env}})U^{\dagger}\big] \\
&= \sum_{k} \big(I_{\mathcal{H}}\otimes \langle e_{k} |_{\mathrm{env}}\big)\big[U(\rho_{in} \otimes |e_0\rangle_{\mathrm{env}}\langle e_0|_{\mathrm{env}})U^{\dagger}\big]\big(I_{\mathcal{H}}\otimes |e_{k} \rangle_{\mathrm{env}}\big)
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1) \\
&= \sum_{k} E_{k} \rho_{\mathrm{in}} E_{k}^{\dagger},
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)
\end{split}
$$
If we define
$$
E_{k} = \big(I_{\mathcal{H}}\otimes \langle e_{k} |_{\mathrm{env}}\big)U\big(I_{\mathcal{H}}\otimes |e_{0}\rangle_{\mathrm{env}}\big). \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(3)
$$
I wonder what happens mathematically from (1) to (2) when we reorder all the terms. How can we break up the tensor product in the middle so easily ($\rho_{in} \otimes |e_0\rangle_{\mathrm{env}}\langle e_0|_{\mathrm{env}}$) and move $|e_0\rangle_{\mathrm{env}}$ to the left beyond $\rho_{in}$? I assume this is because $\rho_{in}$ and $\rho_{env}$ live in different Hilbert spaces. But I still do not know which properties of the tensor product we are using here.
I further found this answer which hints at the property
$$(A\otimes B)(C\otimes D)=(AC)\otimes(BD),$$
but I do not seem to make the trick work here, considering $\rho_{in}$ as $\rho_{in} I_{\mathcal{H}}$ would lead to
$$
\rho_{in} \otimes |e_0\rangle_{\mathrm{env}}\langle e_0|_{\mathrm{env}}
= 
(\rho_{in} I_{\mathcal{H}}) \otimes (|e_0\rangle_{\mathrm{env}}\langle e_0|_{\mathrm{env}}) \\
=
(\rho_{in} \otimes |e_0\rangle_{\mathrm{env}})(I_{\mathcal{H}} \otimes \langle e_0|_{\mathrm{env}}).
$$
This is where I get stuck, and I am not even sure if what I am doing is mathematically correct. However, it seems to be going in the right direction.
Is there maybe even a simple example of why both density operators do not influence each other?

You have
$$\rho_{\rm in}\otimes|e_0\rangle\!\langle e_0|
= (\rho_{\rm in}\otimes I)(I\otimes |e_0\rangle\!\langle e_0|)
= (I\otimes |e_0\rangle\!\langle e_0|)(\rho_{\rm in}\otimes I).
$$
The main "mathematical property" I'm using here is the fact that local operators acting on different spaces commute, that is:
$$(A\otimes I)(I\otimes B)=(I\otimes B)(A\otimes I)\tag1 .$$
You can see this as a direct consequence of the more general identity you quoted:
$$(A\otimes B)(C\otimes D)=(AC)\otimes(BD). \tag2$$
Check that applying (2) to both sides of (1) you get the same result, as $AI=IA=A$, and same for $B$.
After commuting the operators in the first equation you can "split" the bits of $|e_0\rangle\!\langle e_0|$ to get the wanted expression:
$$U(I\otimes |e_0\rangle\!\langle e_0|)
=U(I\otimes |e_0\rangle)(I\otimes \langle e_0|)
= (U(I\otimes |e_0\rangle))(I\otimes \langle e_0|).$$
Note that here $(I\otimes |e_0\rangle)$ and $(I\otimes \langle e_0|)$ are not operators like $U$ and $\rho_{\rm in}$ are.
They are a tensor product of the operator $I$, and the vector $|e_0\rangle$ (or dual vector $\langle e_0|$), which makes them a somewhat weird object.
I think the best way to understand these is to interpret the expressions as handy shorthand to denote linear functions mapping bipartite operators into smaller operators.
That is, you can think of $I\otimes |e_0\rangle$ are really a function that sends the bipartite operator $U$, acting on some space $\mathbb{C}^n\otimes \mathbb{C}^m$, into the operator $U(I\otimes |e_0\rangle)$, which acts in the space $\mathbb{C}^n$, and is defined as you would expect (or you can more concretely think of it as a rectangular matrix, that also works, and is what you'd do if you implemented this stuff numerically).
I'd also note that when you "split" a ketbra, what you are effectively doing is observing that a product of operators like $A(|e\rangle\!\langle f|)B$ is equal to the outer product $(A|e\rangle)(\langle f|B)$ between the vector $A|e\rangle$ and the dual vector $\langle f|B$. In the first expression, $|e\rangle\!\langle f|$ is an operator (a matrix, if you like). In the second expression, $|e\rangle$ and $|f\rangle$ are separate vectors, and $\langle f|$ is a dual vector (meaning a functional).
I don't know if you were looking for this (or more) amount of formal details, but I think it's worth keeping in mind what you're actually doing mathematically when manipulating kets and bras. See also this answer for more discussion about this.

Thank you for explaining why operators can commute here. However, where does the "split up" of $|e_0\rangle\ \langle e_0|$ happen such that $|e_0\rangle$ ends up on the left of $\rho$ and $\langle e_0|$ on the right of $\rho$?

@zuluratman I added some discussion of that
